# Appending from a list inside a list in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
import sys
alphabet = ("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z")
rotor1 = ("p","l","m","k","o","n","j","i","b","h","u","v","g","y","c","f","t","x","d","r","z","s","e","a","w","q")
rotor2 = ("e","b","h","r","k","a","s","t","i","u","m","z","g","y","q","v","d","l","c","x","n","w","o","p","f","j")
rotor3 = ("test")
rotors = (alphabet,rotor1,rotor2,rotor3)
reflector = ("test")

def menu():
    print "Welcome to the Enigma machine!"
    print "------------------------------"
    print "1) Encrypt your message"
    print "2) Change the connections on the plugboard"
    print "3) Exit the program"
    userchoice = raw_input("Please choose an option")

    if userchoice == "1":
        encrypt()
    elif userchoice == "2":
        plugboard()
    elif userchoice == "3":
        sys.exit()

def encrypt():
    alphapos = []
    rotor1pos = []
    encryptedword = []
    userinput = raw_input("Please enter the message that needs to be encrypted")
    usermsglist = list(userinput)
    for x in range(0,2):
        for i in range(0,len(usermsglist)):
            alphapos.append(rotors[x].index(usermsglist[i]))
            encryptedword.append(rotor1[alphapos[i]])
            usermsglist = ''.join(encryptedword)
    print usermsglist
```

I'm trying to make a for loop to make my code more effecient for my enigma machine. But I get an error when I  append from an item within the rotors list which is the list alphabet

I get the error

```
IndexError: string index out of range
```

This is line of code which is causing the error specifically the **rotors[x]** part but if i change it to alphabet the program works fine:

```
alphapos.append(rotors[x].index(usermsglist[i]))
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), correctly formatted, and the full error traceback.

Comment: In which line you get that error?

Comment: `rotor3` is not defined in your code, neither is `raw_input`

Comment: @NuclearPeon `raw_input` is built into Python (2.x).

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thank you for clarifying that! I was using python3. @user3813953: You should be using `for i, x in enumerate(userinput)` instead of assigning `usermsglist` to a list of `userinput`. https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your index management. I changed your loop to use `enumerate` and I get a result without the code erroring out on me.

```
import sys
alphabet = ("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z")
rotor1 = ("p","l","m","k","o","n","j","i","b","h","u","v","g","y","c","f","t","x","d","r","z","s","e","a","w","q")
rotor2 = ("e","b","h","r","k","a","s","t","i","u","m","z","g","y","q","v","d","l","c","x","n","w","o","p","f","j")
rotor3 = ("test")
rotors = (alphabet,rotor1,rotor2,rotor3)
reflector = ("test")

def menu():
    print "Welcome to the Enigma machine!"
    print "------------------------------"
    print "1) Encrypt your message"
    print "2) Change the connections on the plugboard"
    print "3) Exit the program"
    userchoice = raw_input("Please choose an option")

    if userchoice == "1":
        encrypt()
    elif userchoice == "2":
        plugboard()
    elif userchoice == "3":
        sys.exit()

def encrypt():
    alphapos = []
    rotor1pos = []
    encryptedword = []
    userinput = raw_input("Please enter the message that needs to be encrypted")
    usermsglist = list(userinput)
    for x in range(0,2):
        for i, s in enumerate(userinput):
            alphapos.append(rotors[x].index(s))
            encryptedword.append(rotor1[alphapos[i]])
            usermsglist = ''.join(encryptedword)
    print usermsglist
```

Result:

```
Please enter the message that needs to be encryptedhello
iovvciovvc
```

**UPDATE:**

After looking more closely at your code, it seems it is failing because you are **reassigning** `usermsglist` **at the end of the first loop iteration**.

The `list` that your loop checks against suddenly changes.

On the first iteration, `usermsglist` gets assigned to `encryptedword` which is a list with a length of `1`. When the loop ticks its value up by 1, it looks for `usermsglist[1]`, but `usermsglist` is equal to `['h']` (in my example) and **has no 1st element, only 0th**

Comment: Ah thanks for pointing that out thanks for your help. I changed my original code to msg = ''.join(encryptedword) and it works!

Answer (score -2):

First of all, your Error comes from you didn't ready `rotor3`.

`rotor[x + 1]` inside the loop cause this error.

Next, efficient way... No this program doesn't seems work....  Try again...

Hint: Use Python `dictionary` or `ord` function.

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but the rotor3 error has been mentioned in the comments. Also, your answer isn't answering the question, but is a criticism which should be left to the comments section

Comment: I see. But I think I don't have to answer entire question.